# Angular project problem with routing in production

Tags: angular, routes, production

I have developed an angular website: everything works fine in test running in my localhost:4200 but when I upload the website to my server I have a big problem with navigation:

this is my routing

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: ':id/main', component: MainComponent }
];
```

and as you can see I can access "MainComponent" with a param :/id in fact in localhost:4200 if I run https://localhost:4200/test/main I access the main component but when I enter http://mywebsite/test/main I get a 404 page not found.
How can I solve?

Comment: You need to configure in the server to redirect all the 404 requests to index.html. because all the navigation's are happening in the client side, When URL is entered 
 in the browser, it will hit in the server and end up in 404 page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the app uses the Angular router, you must configure the server to
>   return the application's host page (index.html) when asked for a file
>   that it does not have.
>
> Clicking a link in an email, entering it in the browser address bar,
>   or merely refreshing the browser while on the hero detail page — all
>   of these actions are handled by the browser itself, outside the
>   running application. The browser makes a direct request to the server
>   for that URL, bypassing the router.
>
> A static server routinely returns index.html when it receives a
>   request for http://www.sample.org/. But it rejects
>   http://www.sample.org/heroes/42 and returns a 404 - Not Found error
>   unless it is configured to return index.html instead.

For more information about configuring serverm, Please visit the [angular documentation site](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#fallback-configuration-examples)

Comment: So if I add "{ path: '', component: AppComponent}," that is what the index load in my routing it should work?

Comment: No. In which server did you host your application?

Comment: It's hosted in Aruba